# Jenkins docker.inside() and shared volumes

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

In a Jenkins job I would share some folders when I run one container inside another.

There are three systems running

- Docker host
- MySql container
- Alpine container (inside)

I can use the "-v" option to share a folder between the host and the MySql container.
But how can I share it between Docker and Alpine, or betwwen Mysql and Alpine ?
Is it possible to use the "--volumes-from" to share folder between the two containers ?

```
pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage('Run Tests') {                    
            parallel {
                stage("Dbms") { 
                    agent { label 'docker' }
                  steps {
                    script {
                        docker.image("mysql:5").withRun('-e "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw" -v /home/jenkins:/home/jenkins:rw,z') { c ->
                            docker.image("maven:3.6-ibmjava-8-alpine").inside("--link ${c.id}:db") {
                                sh 'echo "Hello from Alpine"'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                  }
                }
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Based on your question information, the stage agent should be either the `mysql` or `maven` image. It is unclear why you are stacking running containers inside of each other.

Comment: Jenkins will automatically bind-mount the `WORKDIR` into the container; is that enough for you?  What files are you trying to share?

Comment: @David, I would like to share other resources, like some config files, and cache folders. I have see an example on the web where the inside container is started by Jenkins with the option "–volumes-from" which permit to share all volumes between the first container and the inner one. But at the moment that option is not present and the only volume shared is the workspace. So I wonder if I can pass some option to the "docker.image().inside()" statement to share volumes.

Comment: @Matt my example is correct, it's the [Jenkins's sidecar pattern](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/#running-sidecar-containers). The purpose is to run a second container which (for example) acts as a dbms server for the other container.

Answer (score 0):

I did it. The solution is to add the option *--name* 
and the options *--volumes-from*  as in the following example:

```
pipeline {
  agent none
  stages {
    stage('Run Tests') {
      environment {
        IMAGE1 = "alpine:latest"
        IMAGE2 = "jacobalberty/firebird:fbconsist"
      }
      parallel {
        stage("Dbms") {
          agent {
            label 'docker'
          }
          steps {
            script {
              docker.image("${env.IMAGE2}").withRun('-p 3051:3050 -e ISC_PASSWORD=masterkey -v /home/jenkins/firebird:/firebird/data:rw,z --name firebird') { c ->
                docker.image("${env.IMAGE2}").inside("--link ${c.id}:db --volumes-from firebird") {
                  // Wait until the service is up
                  sh 'while (! nc -v -z -w5 db 3050); do; sleep 1; done'
                  sh 'echo "OK Firebird is running"'
                }
                docker.image("${env.IMAGE1}").inside("--link ${c.id}:db --volumes-from firebird") {
                  sh 'echo "Hello from Alpine. From here Firebird is running on the host db, port 3050"'
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```